# How does the ATF flow between torque converter and the transmission?

Tags: transmission, automatic-transmission, transmission-fluid, torque-converter, atf

I was wondering how exactly the ATF flows between the torque converter and the Transmission, i couldnt see any hydraulic lines connecting the converter and the transmission, how exactly does the ATF circulate between the two parts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the part of the torque converter which is attached to the transmission, there's a big hole. Fluid travels in and out of it through this hole.

[image]

The front of the transmission looks something like the following image. The part which is sticking out is actually two parts. One is the input shaft (center portion) where the power enters the transmission from the torque converter. What goes around that is a stator shaft, which is solid to the transmission. When this is inside the torque converter, fluid flows out between the two parts and into the torque converter. It then flows back into the transmission between the stator and the torque converter itself (the outer part which sticks into the transmission).

[image]

**NOTE:** This is a generalized description. Different transmissions may do it differently. Generally, the fluid flow is contained here.